# Django Grapelli not styling a few pages

Tags: html, css, django

I am working on a project where we are using Django Grapelli to style the admin interface.  The admin.css is working to style most of the site except for a couple pages where none of the styling is coming through.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to where to begin?  I am thinking the pages that are not getting the styling must not have the admin.css referenced in their template.  I am pretty new to Django and Grapelli so thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Have you included a `{% load static %}` or `{% load staticfiles %}` tag on the pages in question?

Comment: Will try that - I will let you know if that works - I am still tracking down where the pages are within the file structure within PyCharm - thanks for you input!

Comment: Might be some files in the Django admin are being used that are not in repository folders.  admin/auth/user is the end of the url.  Someone else is on the project is going to help me locate it but will let you know if that is what is causing it.  thanks!

Comment: Will give an answer here when I get it- some of the files not being styled are outside of the project repository somehow - some admin pages that are in the native django files - thanks

Comment: We brought the native files into the repository that were missing the styling and added {% load static %} and that worked.  Thanks again for your help.